# Is double prime (″) the correct symbol to use for specifying inches?

Tags: symbols

Is the double prime symbol (″) the correct symbol to use when specifying inches? For example:

> 3′11″

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In short, yes. This is mentioned [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_%28symbol%29) and (a nice blog) [here](http://printingpartners.wordpress.com/2011/06/03/the-apostrophe-prime-acute-double-prime-and-quotation-mark/). In addition, it is commonly referenced in typography manuals to specifically use the double prime instead of the quotation mark, or the double apostrophe.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as [Wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Inch) will also confirm.